# PHP array displaying for values and variables

Tags: php, arrays

```
$states = array( 
        "NSW" => "NSW",
        "VIC" => "VIC",
        "QLD" => "QLD",
        "SA" => "SA",
        "WA" => "WA",
        "TAS" => "TAS",
        "NT" => "NT",
        "ACT" => "ACT",
        "OTH" => "OTH (AUS)",
        "OVS" => "OVS (Overseas)"
        );
```

now I want the values to be the values of `select` and variables.

```
foreach ($states as $key  => $value) {
    $form_ret .= "<option value='".$key."'>".$key[1]."</option>";
}
```

but I can't get the exact value of `OVS (Overseas)` from `OVS`..

what I really want to get is like this:

```
<select name="State" id="State" >
<option value="NSW">NSW </option>
<option value="VIC">VIC </option>
<option value="QLD">QLD </option>
<option value="SA">SA </option>
<option value="WA">WA </option>
<option value="TAS">TAS </option>
<option value="NT">NT </option>
<option value="ACT">ACT </option>
<option value="OTH">OTH (AUS)</option>
<option value="OVS">OVS (Overseas)</option>
</select>
```

does anyone have an idea about my case? thanks in advance

Comment: `$form_ret .= "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";` Maybe use the value variable?!

Comment: Instead of `$key[1]` you just use `$value`?

Comment: Déjà vue? @Rizier123 - *down below...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute `$key[1]` for `$value`:

```
foreach ($states as $key => $value) {
    $form_ret .= "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use `$value` instead of `$key[1]`

```
foreach ($states as $key  => $value) {
    $form_ret .= "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Key[1] is not correct for value. It represents char at 1 of your key's string

Must use $value for displaying the right

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<select name="State" id="State">';
foreach ($states as $key => $value){
echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}echo '</select>';
```

This is the HTML out that you should get

```
    <select id="State" name="State">
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
    <option value="SA">SA</option>
    <option value="WA">WA</option>
    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
    <option value="NT">NT</option>
    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    <option value="OTH">OTH (AUS)</option>
    <option value="OVS">OVS (Overseas)</option>
    </select>
```